# How persistent is data I put on my Azure WebApp via FTP?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I've been searching around and can't find any clear answers to this. I need a small amount of data - talking kilobytes, probably not ever reaching megabyte range - available as a file on my Azure instance, outside the web app itself, for a web job to work with. I won't get into why this is necessary, but it is (alternatives have been explored), and the question is now where to put those files. The obvious answer seems to be to connect to the FTP, create a directory, plop them there and work with them there.

I did a quick test and I'm able to create a "downloads" directory within the "data" directory, drop some files in it, and work with them there. It works great for this very small, simple need that I have.

How long will that data stay there? Is that directory purged at any point automatically by the servers? Is that directory part of any backups that are maintained? How "safe" is something I manually put outside the wwwroot folder?

Comment: Can you put them in Blob Storage and work from there? Also Zain's answer is right on point. You can persist data to the root folder in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never be purged. The only folder that can get purged is the %TEMP% folder. All other folders that you have write access to will be persisted forever.

Comment: anything under `d:\local` is local to the instance (temp is under `d:\local\temp`) and under `d:\home` is shared between all instances of the site and is persistent.